# How can I prove that a set is connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

For example,if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is finite, so $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash A$ is connected.

I'm  trying to use the negation of the definition of connected metric space , so can I reach a contradiction in my hypotesis. I wrote this: let $U, V $open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash A$, such  that $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash A =U \cup V$. How can I continue?

Comment: A similar question was asked fairly recently, and the suggestion was "It's easier to show the stronger statement, that the space is path-connected". Have you gone over path-connectedness?

Comment: no, i haven't gone yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no general recipe, it depends on the structure of the set.

In your example, it is straightforward to show that the set is path connected.

Take a large circle containing the set $A$ in its interior. The circle is path connected.
Now choose a point outside the circle, then a straight line from the point towards the origin will intersect the circle, and so there is a path
from this point to any point in the circle.
Finally, take a point inside the circle, and consider all rays (an uncountable number) from the point. At most a finite number will hit points of $A$, hence we see that there is a path
from this point to any point in the circle. It follows that $A^c$ is
(path) connected.

**Addendum**: Suppose $U,V$ are open and $p:[0,1] \to U \cup V$ is continuous with $p(0) \in U, p(1) \in V$. Show that there is some point such that $p(t) \in U \cap V$. In particular, $U \cap V$ is 
not empty.

Comment: when you said "all rays", you mean a "family of linear functions"?

Comment: There are many ways of doing it; let $x$ be some point, then the ray in the direction $d$ is given by $\{x+td\}_{t \ge 0}$. Basically a half line emanating from $x$. You can use just lines passing through $x$ instead.